# How can i change the height of UIPickerView so that i shows more rows (not scale)

Tags: ios, uipickerview

One of my view controllers has 3 elements, a textfield, a custom picker and a button.  I have a lot of screen space and I want to change the height of the picker so that it shows more rows. 
I dont want to scale the picker or distort the elements in any way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a certain height with an autolayout constraint, but it won't give you what want. The pickers have three different heights they support (162, 180, 216) and they don't behave well when forced to a different height.